# write Multiple lines in scala

Tags: scala

This is my code:

```
bufferedWriter.write(Play.current.configuration.getString("play.compile.c.command").get.replace("{objectname}", registerdJobDetails.executableNm.mkString.split('.')(0)).replace("{executablename}", getExecutableFolderName(jobId) + registerdJobDetails.executableNm))
bufferedWriter.newLine()
bufferedWriter.write(Play.current.configuration.getString("play.runable.c.command").get.replace("{objectname}", registerdJobDetails.executableNm.mkString.split('.')(0)))
```

only the first line is getting written but the other lines is not getting written.

I am getting the error as

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get

Answer (score 1):

Most likely is that your problem is that `Play.current.configuration.getString("play.runable.c.command")` Has type `Option[String]` and are calling the `get` method on Option which pretty much should never be called. The world would be a better place if this method didn't even exist. I digress.

If this call to `getString` returns `None`, then the call to `get` throws an exception that there is no value to get.

Comment: play.runable.c.command = "./{executablename}"
is the problem with this command

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Play.current.configuration.getString("play.runable.c.command")`is returning a `None` which will throw an exception when calling `get`.

this should never be done! Use a combination of `map` and `getOrElse` to avoid unexpected behaviour. For instance:

`val runableConfig = Play.current.configuration.getString("play.runable.c.command")
val s = runableConfig.map {
    case runable => 
      runable.replace("{objectname}", registerdJobDetails.executableNm.mkString.split('.')(0)
 }.getOrElse("NO CONFIG FOUND")
bufferedWriter.write(s)`

or you can even make the `bufferedWriter.write(s)` inside the map.

If you are not aware, the `map` method executes when the Option is defined (it's a `Some(x)`) and ignores when the Option is a `None`

> Note: if it's returning a `None` try to debug that. Verify that you have no typos and that you are reading the right configuration file